# Google App Script: move row (only selected columns within the row) to another tab based on value in column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to move rows when a certain value appears in a given column, but I'd like to only move some of the columns within those rows.

this is the script I'm currently using:

```
//Move rows to Des tab from Form tab
function moveSafeRows()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Des');
  var vals=rg0.getValues();
  for(var i=vals.length-1;i>0;i--)
  {
    if(vals[i][3]=='Yes')
    {
      sh1.appendRow(vals[i]);
      sh0.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
}
```

There are 8 columns in the Form tab, but I want to move only the values in columns 1,2,5.

I made a copy similar to the spreadsheet I'm working on, simulating the output I'd like to see in the second tab:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17CRkz71FehikIblgwjHg-r982cUe95WLPI6LiFUr2LI/edit?pli=1#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You are very close.

You can just move the data only from columns 1, 2 and 5 by slicing the `vals` array accordingly:

```
sh1.appendRow([vals[i][0],vals[i][1],vals[i][4]]);
```

Remember, `0` refers to the first column. Therefore, in our example, we are interested in 0, 1 and 4.

---

### Solution:

```
//Move rows to Des tab from Form tab
function moveSafeRows()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Des');
  var vals=rg0.getValues();
  for(var i=vals.length-1;i>0;i--)
  {
    if(vals[i][3]=='Yes')
    {
      sh1.appendRow([vals[i][0],vals[i][1],vals[i][4]]);
      sh0.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
}
```